# Confusion regarding relation in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tangent-spaces

SOLVED IN COMMENTS

In my lectures, [and these lecture notes on page 8 as an example](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/mfds.pdf), there is the relation

$$(((dF)X)f) \circ F = X(f \circ F)$$

where $F:M \rightarrow N$,

$dF:T_p(M) \rightarrow T_F(p)(N)$,

$X$ is a vector field on M and

$f\in C^\infty (N)$

The above are as claimed in the notes. Hoever it seems to me that, while these definitions work for the right hand side, they do not work for the left hand side. In particular, $f \circ F : M \rightarrow N$ but $X$ is a vector field on $M$.

I would appreciate if someone could clarify what is going on with the domains here.

Comment: $dF X $ is a vector field along $F$, so pointwise it's a tangent vector to $N$ in $F(p)$. So you can differentiate $f$ in that point in that direction, but this makes sense only in the image of $F$, hence the $\circ F$...it's also explained in the notes your link points to. The first thing claimed there is that $(dF) X $ is a vector field on $N$

Comment: observe that $f\circ F:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and not $M\rightarrow N$ as you are claiming... So, $X(f\circ F)$ does make sense..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Oh yeah! Of course!

Comment: It is also assumed that $F$ is a diffeomirphism.. Isn't it the case?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes; although I am not exactly sure why that is necessary

Comment: I am using mobile phone and it difficult to type so much... please read the part in the link again...

Comment: From reading the link, it seems to me that we can perfectly well have F not be a diffeomorphism and out relation only hold pointwise. If we want this equality over the whole manifold, then we had better make F a diffeomorphism, so that dF maps between tangent bundles.